# Program to display the steps of the simplex algorithm

Tags: offline, math, algorithms

I am looking for a program having the following features:

- can display all the steps of the simplex algorithm applied to a given linear program
- has a GUI to write down the linear program we are trying to solve

If possible:

- ability to save the linear program
- allow to select pivot
- free
- runs on Windows 7
- offline, i.e. not hosted on some website

The website [MathsTools](http://www.mathstools.com/section/main/simplex_online_calculator) is pretty good but has some bugs and lack the ability to save the linear program:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Lispide](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lipside/) was invented just for you.

- I don't know what you call **all the steps** of a simplex resolution, but it does provide intermediaries rather than just the result in basic mode
- It has a magnificent GUI : [image]
- You can save the program,
- You cannot choose the pivot - it uses the biggest coefficient of the line considered as a pivot. There may be a way to tweak this, but none that I know of.
- It is free
- It is advertised to run on Windows 7, but I've used it only on vista.
- It is offline.